# Effect on Cache Removal if multiple threads tried to change this cache item in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

What would be effects of multiple threads trying to change the Cache by the name of 'CustData' at the same time? Would it cause some errors?  I am using .Net 4.5.

I do not want to use thread synchronization when changing this cache item, as that could slow down cache access in a multi-user ASP.Net app.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove('CustData');
```

Comment: Did you try it and see what happened?

Comment: Not sure what .net framework version you're using, but according the msdn that class is 100% thread safe on latest versions

Comment: @Claudio Redi , Wow. I didn't know. That will solve my problems instantly.

Comment: @Claudio Redi, So all methods like Remove and Insert are thread-safe. Excellent. Can you post your comment as a post so I can mark it as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx), All Cache Class methods are thread safe so you're 100% covered. It's kind of expected since by nature is expected to be used on a multithread context.